# SQL Trigger: New row :tableA to new col in :tableB

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers, pivot

I have a database with a couple of tables. I need to add a column in one table after the insertion of a new row in another table.

```
Table A: id | Type | Category | ShortDesc | LongDesc | Active
Row 1 int(11), varchar, varchar,varchar,varchar,int
Row 2
Row 3

Table B: id | Row1-ShortDesc | Row2-ShortDesc | Row3-ShortDesc
Row 1 int(11), tiny(1), tiny(1), tiny(1) etc...
Row 2 
Row 3
```

When I occasionally add a new row (item) to TableA, I want a new column in TableB. TableA is a long evolving collection. A Row in TableA can not be removed for obvious legacy reasons.

So when I insert a row to TableA I need to have another column inserted/appended into TableB.

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: Micheal I think  the maximum number of columns you can have is 1024 columns in a table, What would you do when there are more than 1024 rows in TableA. In short you are approching this problem in a Veryvery Very wrong way. You should add a row in TableB for each row in TableA and add just One more column in TableB as a description for each row.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I doubt that there will be more than 1000 columns in TableA but I anticipate tens of thousands of rows in TableB.

Comment: I am using mySQL with phpMyAdmin via cPanel on my webhost. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

### Answer derived from training in SQL

I was finally able to derive and create my trigger solution utilizing a class in SQL Server at MAX TRAINING in CINCINNATI OHIO.

--SQL CODE
-- Create a table called TableA that just holds some data for the trigger
-- This table has a primary Key seeded with 1 and incremented by 1

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
shortDesc varchar(60) NOT NULL,
longDesc varchar(60) NOT NULL,
bigDesc TEXT NOT NULL
)
GO
```

-- Create a table TableB that only has a ID column. ID as a primary key seeded with 1, incremented by 1

```
CREATE TABLE TableB(
id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
)
GO
```

-- Just to see the two tables with nothing in it.

```
select * from TableA
select * from TableB
GO
```

-- The actual trigger in TableA based upon an insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_myInserCol
ON TableA
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
-- Don't count the trigger events
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Because we are making strings we declare some variables
    DECLARE @newcol as varchar(60);
    DECLARE @lastRow as int;
    DECLARE @sql as varchar(MAX);
-- Now fill the variables
-- make sure we are looking at the last, freshly inserted row
    SET @lastRow = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA);
-- Make a SELECT statement for the last row
    SET @newcol = (SELECT shortDesc FROM TableA WHERE id = @lastRow);
-- Adds a new column in TableB is inserted based on a
-- TableA.shortDesc as the name of the new column.
-- You can use any row data you want but spaces and
-- special characters will require quotes around the field.
    SET @sql = ('ALTER TABLE TableB ADD ' + @newcol + ' char(99)');
-- And run the SQL statement as a combined string
    exec(@sql);
END;
GO
```

--Insert a new rows into TableA
--The trigger will fire and add a column in TableB

```
INSERT INTO TableA
(name,shortDesc,longDesc,bigDesc)
VALUES ('attract','Attraction','Attractions','Places to go see and have 
fun');
GO
INSERT INTO TableA
(name,shortDesc,longDesc,bigDesc)
VALUES ('camp','Camp','CAMP GROUND','Great place to sleep next to a creek');
GO
(name,shortDesc,longDesc,bigDesc)
VALUES ('fuel','GasStation','Fueling Depot','Get gas and go');
GO
INSERT INTO TableA
(name,shortDesc,longDesc,bigDesc)
VALUES ('petstore','PetStore','Pet Store','Get a friend');
GO
```

-- See the newly created rows in TableA and the new Columns created in TableB

```
select * from TableA
select * from TableB
GO
```

-- Do not execute unless you want to delete the newly created tables.
-- Use this to delete your tables
-- Clean up your work space so you can make changes and try again.

```
DROP TABLE TableA;
DROP TABLE TableB;
GO
```

Thanks again to those that tried to help me out. And yes, I still understand this may not be the best solution but for me this works as I will only insert rows in TableA maybe a couple of times a year and will more than likely max out with less than 300 rows over the next several years as the data I am working with doesn't change that frequently and have a single row to access with a single bit  (T/F) allows me to now quickly assign TableB's to locations and people for their search criteria and to generate a nice SQL query string without multiple reads across potentially several pages. Thanks again!

And if someone wants to add or modify what I have done, I'm all ears. It's all about learning and sharing.

Michael